# Autodestruction Telegram bot in python

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a simple bot for my group that with a command, ban everyone that is not an admin like him, and i tried to implement the tecnology myself, but if i add the command the bot doesnt respond in my group with any command, and if i write myself to the bot it respond with an error for the immission. here is the code:

```
import con as keys
import asyncio
from telegram.ext import *
import responses as r
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch
from telethon.tl.types import (
    PeerChannel
)
import pyrogram
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
import os, sys
import time

print("Iniziamo...")

def pyro_command(update, context):
    chats = []
    last_date = None
    chunk_size = 900
    groups=[]
 
    result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=last_date,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=chunk_size,
             hash = 0
         ))
    chats.extend(result.chats)
    for chat in chats:
        try:
            if chat.group== True:
                groups.append(chat)
        except:
            continue
    print('[+] scegli il gruppo dove vuoi cercare gli utenti:')
    i=0
    for g in groups:
        print([str(i)] + ' - '+ g.title)
        i+=1
 
    print('')
    g_index = input(gr+"[+] inserisci un numero : "+re)
    target_group=groups[int(g_index)]
 
    print(gr+'[+] creo il messaggio...')
    time.sleep(1)
    all_participants = []
    all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)
    print("creo il messaggio...")
    time.sleep(1) 
    for user in all_participants:
        if not update.message.from_user.id in get_admin_ids(bot, update.message.chat_id):#i check if the user is an admin for the message
            #ban the user     
    print('[+] Utenti bannati.')

def start_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("INIZIALIZZAZIONE....")
    for x in range(1, 4):
        update.message.reply_text("Pyro Never Dies.")

def help_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Se hai bisogno di aiuto, chiedi a un Admin!")

def handle_message(update, context):
    text = str(update.message.text).lower()
    response = r.sample_responses(text)

    update.message.reply_text(response)

def error(update, context):
    print(f"update {update} ha causato un errore {context.error}")



try:
    api_id = "info"
    api_hash = "info"
    phone = 'myphonenumber'
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
except KeyError:
    os.system('clear')
    print("Errore.")
client.connect()
print("Client creato e connesso....")
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    os.system('clear')
    client.sign_in(phone, input('[+] Enter the code: '))
 
os.system('clear')

updater = Updater(keys.API_KEY, use_context = True)
dp = updater.dispatcher
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_command))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("pyro", pyro_command))
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, handle_message))
dp.add_error_handler(error)
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

here is the error for the command:

```
[+] scegli il gruppo dove vuoi bannare gli utenti:
update {'message': {'delete_chat_photo': False, 'chat': {'first_name': 'kernel', 'type': 'private', 'id': 5377477821, 'username': 'khagnaccio'}, 'photo': [], 'new_chat_photo': [], 'entities': [{'length': 5, 'type': 'bot_command', 'offset': 0}], 'text': '/pyro', 'group_chat_created': False, 'new_chat_members': [], 'supergroup_chat_created': False, 'date': 1661200420, 'channel_chat_created': False, 'message_id': 125, 'caption_entities': [], 'from': {'id': 5377477821, 'language_code': 'it', 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'kernel', 'username': 'khagnaccio'}}, 'update_id': 967684595} ha causato un errore can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Comment: in line `print([str(i)] + ' - '+ g.title)` you create list `[str(i)]` and you try to add string to this list. It is wrong. Remove `[ ]` to add strings. `print( str(i) + ' - '+ g.title )`. And if you want chars `[ ]` in string then use `"[" + str(i) + "]"`. OR simpler use `f-string` like `print( f"[{i}] - {g.title}" )`

Answer (score 0):

In line

```
print([str(i)] + ' - '+ g.title)
```

you create list `[str(i)]` and you try to add string to this list.

It is wrong.

Put `[ ]` as strings.

```
print('[' + str(i) + ']' + ' - '+ g.title )
```

Or simpler use `f-string`

```
print(f"[{i}] - {g.title}")
```

---

**BTW:** You can use `enumerate()` without `i = 0` and `i += 1`

```
for i, g in enumerate(groups):
    print(f"[{i}] - {g.title}')
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but i have a few more problems, firs the bot reply to the command only when i write directly to him, in the group he doesn't reply, and when i try the /pyro, it gives another error: ha causato un errore There is no current event loop in thread 'Bot:5561807213:dispatcher'.
/home/elias/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py:575: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ChatMethods.get_participants' was never awaited
  self.logger.exception('An uncaught error was raised while handling the error.')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: now you have new problem and you should write new question on new page. And new people will see it - and they may help you.